# Disable city ranged attack notifications for aliens?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

I'm trying to focus on harmony, but the game tells me every turn that I can perform a ranged attack on the aliens nearby my city.
Can I somehow tell the game I don't want to attack aliens?

Comment: There's no requirement for you to follow through on those.  It'll let you end the turn without attacking, so ignoring it is one option.

Comment: @Frank I know, but it's disturbing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's an option, but I'm not at home to verify this.

Comment: @Ellesedil Can't see any option, at least in the "Gameplay" tab in Options.

Comment: What about building the fence city improvement that makes it so the aliens will never get within bombard range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the only way to get rid of them is to build the ultrasonic fence, which will prevent aliens from wandering into bombardment range altogether.
It does not address the problem of unwanted notifications, but it does accomplish what you want.

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution, left click on the notification in the bottom right then left click on it. It goes away.

Comment: That gets rid of for that turn. But how do you turn it off permanently?